# How do you change Advanced Matching Personal info after init FB Pixel with other info?

Tags: javascript, facebook, analytics, single-page-application, facebook-pixel

After initializing the Facebook Pixel with personal information for Advanced Matching, are you allowed to change the personal information for Advanced Matching? This is for a Single Page Application. I tried to initialize the Facebook Pixel again with new personal information, and the pixel still was reporting the original Advanced Matching info that I initialized with.

For example, we would run:

`window.fbq('init', <FACEBOOK_ID>, { em: <email> });`

On a later page we get more information about them, so we would run:

`window.fbq('init', <FACEBOOK_ID>, { em: <email>, st: <state> })`

The new infomation, in this example state info, is not being reported.

Comment: Don’t see any other method in the docs that would make it possible to change this info after the pixel has already been initialized. Guess you could try and use the image version of the pixel to get this data send, but in that case you have to hash it yourself before you append the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using single page application so you have to do init again, This is not possible to append the advance parameter.

```
window.fbq('init', <FACEBOOK_ID>, { em: <email>, st: <state> })
```

Facebook always fire the event after initializing the pixel so in your first line code call was already sent to faecbook and that's fire. Now if you want to send another parameter then you have to send the call to facebook again with init.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work as the pixel responds with: `[Facebook Pixel] - Duplicate Pixel ID: ...`

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this while also working with a Single Page Application (SPA) by just sending the information using a pixel based on an image after the Javascript's one was initialized with the `init` event.

I used the following code:

```
var fbtag = document.createElement('img');
var user_email = 'USER_HASHED_EMAIL_IN_SHA256';
var pixel_id = 'XXXXXXXXX';
fbtag.src = 'https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=' + pixel_id + '&ev=PageView&ud[em]=' + user_email;
document.body.appendChild(fbtag);
```

You can also do the same for a Lead standard event:

```
var fbtag = document.createElement('img');
var user_email = 'USER_HASHED_EMAIL_IN_SHA256';
var pixel_id = 'XXXXXXXXX';
fbtag.src = 'https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=' + pixel_id + '&ev=Lead&ud[em]=' + user_email;
document.body.appendChild(fbtag);
```

Or, of course, for a Purchase vent where extra data is added to the URL:

```
var fbtag = document.createElement('img');
var user_email = 'USER_HASHED_EMAIL_IN_SHA256';
var pixel_id = 'XXXXXXXXX';
var purchase_value = '999';
var purchase_currency = 'EUR';
var content_ids = '123,456,789'; // content identifiers separated by commas

fbtag.src = 'https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=' + pixel_id + '&ev=Purchase&ud[em]=' + user_email + '&cd[value]=' + purchase_value + '&cd[content_ids]=' + content_ids + '&cd[currency]=' + purchase_currency;
document.body.appendChild(fbtag);
```

I know this is not perfect, but I've started to see advanced matching information in Facebook, so I guess it works properly :).

Just please remember that you should use SHA256 over the user's email address before sending it to Facebook to avoid issues with the GDPR laws :).